# Recursively remove an ACE

Tags: macos, unix, permissions, operating-system, acl

Really quick. Is it possible to recursively strip a specific users full ACE from everywhere in a directory?

something like chmod -R -a "_spotlight:*" /Volumes/DATA/

??

ON OS X 10.6.8

setfacls and getfacls dont exist on OS X

Answer (score 0):

ACLs are managed using chmod on OS X.
The standard trick is to recursively remove all ACLs, then reapply at top level with inheritance set.
Or else you can write some script to using ls -le to list the ACLs, grab the index for a given user/group and then remove that entry.
like:

```
chmod -a# $(ls -le filename | awk '/username/ {print substr ($1,0,1)}') filename
```